# Getting Error Related to Webpack When Doing Unit Test for Vue

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, webpack, isparta

I had started a webapp, by modifying [vue-hackernews-2.0](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0). I started to write unit tests as well for it.

I am getting following `webpack` error while setting up unit test for my Vue web app:

```
23 11 2016 17:13:18.968:ERROR [preprocess]: Can not load "webpack"!
  WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration has an unknown property 'vue'. These properties are valid:
   object { amd?, bail?, cache?, context?, dependencies?, devServer?, devtool?, entry, externals?, loader?, module?, name?, node?, output?, plugins?, profile?, recordsInputPath?, recordsOutputPath?, recordsPath?, resolve?, resolveLoader?, stats?, target?, watch?, watchOptions? }
   For typos: please correct them.
   For loader options: webpack 2 no longer allows custom properties in configuration.
     Loaders should be updated to allow passing options via loader options in module.rules.
     Until loaders are updated one can use the LoaderOptionsPlugin to pass these options to the loader:
     plugins: {
       new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
         // test: /\.xxx$/, // may apply this only for some modules
         options: {
           vue: ...
         }
       })
     }
 - configuration.module has an unknown property 'preLoaders'. These properties are valid:
   object { exprContextCritical?, exprContextRecursive?, exprContextRegExp?, exprContextRequest?, loaders?, noParse?, rules?, unknownContextCritical?, unknownContextRecursive?, unknownContextRegExp?, unknownContextRequest?, wrappedContextCritical?, wrappedContextRecursive?, wrappedContextRegExp? }
   Options affecting the normal modules (`NormalModuleFactory`).
    at webpack (/Users/saurabh.mimani/work/codes/jeeves/vue/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:16:9)
    at new Plugin (/Users/saurabh.mimani/work/codes/jeeves/vue/node_modules/karma-webpack/lib/karma-webpack.js:63:18)
    at invoke (/Users/saurabh.mimani/work/codes/jeeves/vue/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:75:15)
    at Array.instantiate (/Users/saurabh.mimani/work/codes/jeeves/vue/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:59:20)
    at get (/Users/saurabh.mimani/work/codes/jeeves/vue/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:48:43)
    at /Users/saurabh.mimani/work/codes/jeeves/vue/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:71:14
    at Array.map (native)
    at Array.invoke (/Users/saurabh.mimani/work/codes/jeeves/vue/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:70:31)
    at Injector.get (/Users/saurabh.mimani/work/codes/jeeves/vue/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:48:43)
    at instantiatePreprocessor (/Users/saurabh.mimani/work/codes/jeeves/vue/node_modules/karma/lib/preprocessor.js:55:20)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at createPreprocessor (/Users/saurabh.mimani/work/codes/jeeves/vue/node_modules/karma/lib/preprocessor.js:74:20)
    at Array.invoke (/Users/saurabh.mimani/work/codes/jeeves/vue/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:75:15)
    at get (/Users/saurabh.mimani/work/codes/jeeves/vue/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:48:43)
    at /Users/saurabh.mimani/work/codes/jeeves/vue/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:71:14
    at Array.map (native)
23 11 2016 17:13:19.006:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
23 11 2016 17:13:19.017:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.3.0 server started at http://localhost:9876/
23 11 2016 17:13:19.017:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers Chrome, Firefox, PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency
23 11 2016 17:13:19.018:ERROR [karma]: Found 1 load error
```

The following is my `karma.conf.js`:

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Wed Nov 23 2016 13:59:48 GMT+0530 (IST)

var path = require('path')
var merge = require('webpack-merge')
var baseConfig = require('../build/webpack.base.config')
var projectRoot = path.resolve(__dirname, '../')

var webpackConfig = merge(baseConfig, {
  // use inline sourcemap for karma-sourcemap-loader
  devtool: '#inline-source-map',
  vue: {
    loaders: {
      js: 'isparta'
    }
  }
})

// no need for app entry during tests
delete webpackConfig.entry

// make sure isparta loader is applied before eslint
webpackConfig.module.preLoaders.unshift({
  test: /\.js$/,
  loader: 'isparta',
  include: projectRoot,
  exclude: /test\/unit|node_modules/
})

// only apply babel for test files when using isparta
webpackConfig.module.rules.some(function (loader, i) {
  if (loader.loader === 'babel') {
    loader.include = /test\/unit/
    return true
  }
})

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: ['./index.js'],

    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
      './index.js': ['webpack']
    },
    webpack: webpackConfig,
    webpackMiddleware: {
      noInfo: true
    },
    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['spec', 'coverage', 'progress'],
    coverageReporter: {
      dir: './coverage',
      reporters: [
        { type: 'lcov', subdir: '.' },
        { type: 'text-summary' }
      ]
    },


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome', 'Firefox', 'PhantomJS'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

The following are the versions:

```
"vue": "^2.0.0",
"karma": "^1.3.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
"karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
"karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.0.0",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
"karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
"karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.26",
"karma-webpack": "^1.8.0",
"vue-loader": "^9.7.0",
"webpack": "^2.1.0-beta.25",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.12.2",
"webpack-merge": "^0.17.0"
```

Comment: Are you using .vue files ? You installed vue-loader but I can't see it set in your webpack config ?

Comment: @Ikostke I  have that in webpack.base.config.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a configuration for webpack 1.x, but your webpack version is 2.x.

In webpack 1.x you could have custom options on the config. Vue made use of this by using a vue property on the config. Now, in webpack 2.x you can not do this.

Hackernews now supports webpack 2.x, so if you download a fresh version it will compile correctly.